# How does vim decide if a file is "readonly"?

Tags: security

For testing purposes I set the `setuid` to my `vim` binary. Now when I open for example `/etc/passwd`, modify the file and execute `:w`, then I get the `E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)` error message. However, the `:w!` saves the changes, i.e it is not a file-system restriction.
Based on what rules vim considers certain files as read-only?

Comment: Do you have write permissions for the file?

Comment: I'm running `vim` as user `root` and with `:w!` I'm able to write the file.

Comment: Ok, well, does root have write permission?

Comment: Yes. And as I wrote, with `:w!` I'm able to save my changes to the file, i.e file system permissions allow `root` user to change the file.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick experiment:

```sh
# touch readonly
# chmod a-w readonly
```

Now, `vim readonly` will start in readonly mode, because the current user does not have write permission. But, as root or as a regular user (file owner only? untested with other regular users), `w!` can bypass this.

Also, from the help, `vim` will start with `'readonly'` set if

- vim starts with the `-R` flag
- the executable is named `view`

> When using ":w!" the 'readonly' option is reset for the current
>       buffer, unless the 'Z' flag is in 'cpoptions'.
>       When using the ":view" command the 'readonly' option is set for the
>       newly edited buffer. (`:h 'readonly'`)

Comment: That's odd, because `/etc/passwd` has `w` for user `root`: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1571 May  8 13:19 /etc/passwd`. I guess it has nothing to do with `vim`, but rather how Linux executes the `setuid` binaries.

Comment: @Martin a setuid binary will execute with an EUID ("effective" UID) of root (or the user that owns the binary), but still an UID ("real" UID) of your user. Functions to explicitly check for access ([`access(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/access)) typically use the *real* UID. A setuid process that wants to actually run as root will typically execute `setreuid(geteuid()):` to reset the real UID appropriately. Hope that helps!